# Save answers data and import it in other android device

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a trivia app developed in Android Studio. First user answer all the questions and finally I want to save this answers with an unique identifyer because then I want to show this answers in other device by entering this id in a text view.

It is possible with Firebase?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you could use Google Play Games API, not sure though, have a look here: https://developers.google.com/games/services/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible with **Firebase**

My recommendation is **backendless.com**, much simpler

[android sdk](https://backendless.com/documentation/users/android/users_overview.htm)

[ios sdk](https://backendless.com/documentation/users/ios/users_overview.htm)